# Binary Insertion Sort Implementation Python

Tags: python, sorting, binary-search, insertion-sort

While studying algorithms, I found an algorithm, which is basically an Insertion Sort but it uses Binary Search instead of WHILE-loop statement in shifting elements backward.

I wrote the following implementation code and it works fine with given inputs.

My question is 1) Are there any improvements to my code? 2) I still cannot understand why it has quadratic time despite using binary search. I think I need help in understanding this.

Thank you for your valued advice in advance :)

```
A=[3,25,18,41,52,26,38,57,9,49]
def InsertionSort_improved(A):
    for k in range(1,len(A)):
        key = A[k]
        low = 0
        high = k-1
        BinarySearch(A,low,high,key,k)

def BinarySearch(A,low,high,key,k):
    if low<high:
        mid= (low+high)//2
        if A[mid] == key:
            for i in range(k,mid,-1):
                A[i] = A[i-1]
            A[i-1] = key
        elif A[mid] < key:
            BinarySearch(A, mid+1, high, key, k)
        else:
            BinarySearch(A, low, mid, key, k)
    else:
        mid=(low+high)//2
        if A[mid]>key:
            for j in range(k,mid,-1):
                A[j] = A[j-1]
            A[j-1] = key

InsertionSort_improved(A)
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: because of these two lines.

```py
for j in range(k,mid,-1):
    A[j] = A[j-1]
```

Insertion of an element goes like this:

- find where to insert the new element;
- shift a lot of elements to make room for the new element.

The code you've found uses binary search to speed up the first step, which becomes `O(log(n))` instead of `O(n)`.

But then it still needs to shift the elements, and this is done with a simple for-loop, which takes `O(n)` time.

Note that when doing insertion sort on a linked list instead of an array, shifting is no longer necessary, so the second step becomes `O(1)`... But with a linked list, binary search is not possible, so the first step remains `O(n)`.

Conclusion: on arrays as well as on linked lists, insertion sorts remains a quadratic algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! It really helped me a lot! Now I understood the point - although I adopted Binary Search, it still needs to shift elements, which takes O(n) time.